# springboot fails while running bootRun for gradle project

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Getting below error after upgrading springboot multi module project to springboot 2 with gradle 5.x. I do not see any project specific exception in stack trace. Basically, the project structure is like below:

```
 application:
     module1
         build.gradle    
     module2
         build.gradle
```

When I put a break point at SpringApplication.java of spring-boot class, it's breaking on below piece of code

```
protected void bindToSpringApplication(ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    try {
        Binder.get(environment).bind("spring.main", Bindable.ofInstance(this));
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot bind to SpringApplication", ex);
    }
}
```

And the exception is:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]



ConversionService converters =
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.lang.Long -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,@org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Long -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@36ddaebf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@3cff0139
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.LocalTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@9d7ccfe
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.OffsetTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.OffsetTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@15f8701f
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@4b2e3e8f
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Calendar -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,org.joda.time.LocalDate -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.ReadablePartialPrinter@2cec704c
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,org.joda.time.LocalDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.ReadablePartialPrinter@240f6c41
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,org.joda.time.LocalTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.ReadablePartialPrinter@2416498e
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.ReadableInstant -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,org.joda.time.ReadableInstant -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.ReadableInstantPrinter@2015b2cd
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Byte -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Double -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Float -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Integer -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Short -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.math.BigDecimal -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.math.BigInteger -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    [C -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.boot.convert.CharArrayFormatter@5e746d37
    java.lang.Boolean -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@2e23c180
    java.lang.Character -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.CharacterToNumberFactory@173f73e7
    java.lang.Character -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@46d567cb
    java.lang.Enum -> java.lang.Integer : org.springframework.core.convert.support.EnumToIntegerConverter@396e6d9
    java.lang.Enum -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.EnumToStringConverter@4efc25fc
    java.lang.Integer -> java.lang.Enum : org.springframework.core.convert.support.IntegerToEnumConverterFactory@7ee3d262
    java.lang.Long -> java.time.Instant : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$LongToInstantConverter@732c9b5c
    java.lang.Long -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$LongToCalendarConverter@2d23faef,java.lang.Long -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$LongToCalendarConverter@7cb8437d
    java.lang.Long -> java.util.Date : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$LongToDateConverter@1aac188d,java.lang.Long -> java.util.Date : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$LongToDateConverter@7026b7ee
    java.lang.Long -> org.joda.time.ReadableInstant : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$LongToReadableInstantConverter@6b0615ae
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.Character : org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToCharacterConverter@363a3d15
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.NumberToNumberConverterFactory@162b3d47
    java.lang.Number -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@3402b4c9
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.lang.Long: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Long: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDate: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.LocalDate: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@213c3543
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.LocalDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@7c29adc8
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.LocalTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.LocalTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@670ce331
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.OffsetTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.OffsetTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@514cd540
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.ZonedDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.ZonedDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@4bbb49b0
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Calendar: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalDate: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.LocalDate: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.LocalDateParser@771cbb1a
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.LocalDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.LocalDateTimeParser@3659d7b1
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.LocalTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.LocalTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.LocalTimeParser@6b2e0f78
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat org.joda.time.ReadableInstant: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaDateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@cb03411,java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.ReadableInstant: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.DateTimeParser@3bdb2c78
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Byte: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Double: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Float: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Integer: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.lang.Short: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.math.BigDecimal: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.math.BigInteger: org.springframework.format.number.NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@431f1eaf
    java.lang.String -> [C: org.springframework.boot.convert.CharArrayFormatter@5e746d37
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Boolean : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToBooleanConverter@43a51d00
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Character : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCharacterConverter@95bb2a2
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Enum : org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToEnumIgnoringCaseConverterFactory@499683c4,java.lang.String -> java.lang.Enum : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToEnumConverterFactory@25da615a
    java.lang.String -> java.lang.Number : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToNumberConverterFactory@783115d9
    java.lang.String -> java.net.InetAddress: org.springframework.boot.convert.InetAddressFormatter@6e1b9411
    java.lang.String -> java.nio.charset.Charset : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCharsetConverter@3a5c2626
    java.lang.String -> java.time.Instant: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.InstantFormatter@11d4dbd6
    java.lang.String -> java.time.Month: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.MonthFormatter@186cb891
    java.lang.String -> java.time.MonthDay: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.MonthDayFormatter@440eaa07
    java.lang.String -> java.time.OffsetDateTime: org.springframework.boot.convert.IsoOffsetFormatter@f096f37,java.lang.String -> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.OffsetDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.lang.String -> java.time.OffsetDateTime: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorParser@41f4fe5
    java.lang.String -> java.time.Period: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.PeriodFormatter@6f4ade6e
    java.lang.String -> java.time.Year: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.YearFormatter@86733
    java.lang.String -> java.time.YearMonth: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.YearMonthFormatter@3ec2ecea
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Currency : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCurrencyConverter@7fb33394
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Locale : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToLocaleConverter@75308740
    java.lang.String -> java.util.Properties : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToPropertiesConverter@1a891add
    java.lang.String -> java.util.TimeZone : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToTimeZoneConverter@6009bea
    java.lang.String -> java.util.UUID : org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToUUIDConverter@373f7450
    java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.Duration: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.DurationFormatter@1c758545
    java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.MonthDay: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.MonthDayFormatter@73a19967
    java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.Period: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.PeriodFormatter@64693226
    java.lang.String -> org.joda.time.YearMonth: org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.YearMonthFormatter@117bcfdc
    java.net.InetAddress -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.boot.convert.InetAddressFormatter@6e1b9411
    java.nio.charset.Charset -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@e48bf9a
    java.time.Instant -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$InstantToLongConverter@38320e34
    java.time.Instant -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.InstantFormatter@11d4dbd6
    java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$LocalDateTimeToLocalDateConverter@62a4417
    java.time.LocalDateTime -> java.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$LocalDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter@43f61afb
    java.time.Month -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.MonthFormatter@186cb891
    java.time.MonthDay -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.MonthDayFormatter@440eaa07
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.boot.convert.IsoOffsetFormatter@f096f37,@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.lang.String: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.Jsr310DateTimeFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory@3d6a6bee,java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.TemporalAccessorPrinter@3effd4f3
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.time.Instant : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToInstantConverter@367b22e5
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToLocalDateConverter@3e5d4f6b
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.time.LocalDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverter@5ae95707
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter@39c1fe0b
    java.time.OffsetDateTime -> java.time.ZonedDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$OffsetDateTimeToZonedDateTimeConverter@62891fc8
    java.time.Period -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.PeriodFormatter@6f4ade6e
    java.time.Year -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.YearFormatter@86733
    java.time.YearMonth -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.YearMonthFormatter@3ec2ecea
    java.time.ZoneId -> java.util.TimeZone : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ZoneIdToTimeZoneConverter@7bc6d27a
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.time.Instant : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToInstantConverter@1ac45389
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToLocalDateConverter@713064e8
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.time.LocalDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverter@1bf39d06
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter@4fad6218
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.time.OffsetDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$ZonedDateTimeToOffsetDateTimeConverter@68217d41
    java.time.ZonedDateTime -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ZonedDateTimeToCalendarConverter@75769ab0
    java.util.Calendar -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$CalendarToLongConverter@5a00eb1e,java.util.Calendar -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$CalendarToLongConverter@36fcf6c0
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.Instant : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToInstantConverter@4c48fe92
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToLocalDateConverter@3ae0b770
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.LocalDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToLocalDateTimeConverter@30e6a763
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToLocalTimeConverter@55e3d6c3
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.OffsetDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToOffsetDateTimeConverter@10bd9df0
    java.util.Calendar -> java.time.ZonedDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters$CalendarToZonedDateTimeConverter@fca387
    java.util.Calendar -> java.util.Date : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$CalendarToDateConverter@6dd82486,java.util.Calendar -> java.util.Date : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$CalendarToDateConverter@56078cea
    java.util.Calendar -> org.joda.time.ReadableInstant : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$CalendarToReadableInstantConverter@49c8f6e8
    java.util.Currency -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@41bf79da
    java.util.Date -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$DateToLongConverter@4c59e45e,java.util.Date -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$DateToLongConverter@58ec7116
    java.util.Date -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$DateToCalendarConverter@63bde6c2,java.util.Date -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.format.datetime.DateFormatterRegistrar$DateToCalendarConverter@6ea04618
    java.util.Date -> org.joda.time.ReadableInstant : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateToReadableInstantConverter@2f98635e
    java.util.Locale -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@5acc9fdf
    java.util.Properties -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.PropertiesToStringConverter@5176d279
    java.util.UUID -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@d74bac4
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> java.lang.Long : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToLongConverter@7afbf561
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> java.util.Calendar : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToCalendarConverter@7c9bdee9
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> java.util.Date : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToDateConverter@4f453e63
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.DateMidnight : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToDateMidnightConverter@624a24f6
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.Instant : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToInstantConverter@338cc75f
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToLocalDateConverter@7fc7c4a
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.LocalDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToLocalDateTimeConverter@53a5e217
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToLocalTimeConverter@7aa9e414
    org.joda.time.DateTime -> org.joda.time.MutableDateTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$DateTimeToMutableDateTimeConverter@6b00ad9
    org.joda.time.Duration -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.DurationFormatter@1c758545
    org.joda.time.LocalDateTime -> org.joda.time.LocalDate : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$LocalDateTimeToLocalDateConverter@4e73b552
    org.joda.time.LocalDateTime -> org.joda.time.LocalTime : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.JodaTimeConverters$LocalDateTimeToLocalTimeConverter@221dad51
    org.joda.time.MonthDay -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.MonthDayFormatter@73a19967
    org.joda.time.Period -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.PeriodFormatter@64693226
    org.joda.time.YearMonth -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.joda.YearMonthFormatter@117bcfdc
    org.springframework.boot.convert.ArrayToDelimitedStringConverter@2c768ada,org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@c1fca2a
    org.springframework.boot.convert.CollectionToDelimitedStringConverter@5d5b5fa7,org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToStringConverter@2a32fb6
    org.springframework.boot.convert.DelimitedStringToArrayConverter@5533dc72,org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToArrayConverter@7c447c76
    org.springframework.boot.convert.DelimitedStringToCollectionConverter@6107165,org.springframework.core.convert.support.StringToCollectionConverter@164a62bf
    org.springframework.boot.convert.DurationToNumberConverter@5ec46cdd
    org.springframework.boot.convert.DurationToStringConverter@39e43310,java.time.Duration -> java.lang.String : org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DurationFormatter@eb507b9
    org.springframework.boot.convert.NumberToDataSizeConverter@112d1c8e
    org.springframework.boot.convert.NumberToDurationConverter@21d1b321
    org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToDataSizeConverter@2324bfe7
    org.springframework.boot.convert.StringToDurationConverter@390877d2,java.lang.String -> java.time.Duration: org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DurationFormatter@eb507b9
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToArrayConverter@74aa9c72
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToCollectionConverter@5ff90645
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToObjectConverter@64fc097e
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4aaae508
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4aaae508
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4aaae508
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ByteBufferConverter@4aaae508
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToArrayConverter@387bf2d9
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToCollectionConverter@5c20aab9
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.CollectionToObjectConverter@11ebb1b6
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.FallbackObjectToStringConverter@27ace0b1
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.IdToEntityConverter@6869a3b3,org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToObjectConverter@6ab4ba9f
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.MapToMapConverter@4b7c4456
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToArrayConverter@1640c151
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToCollectionConverter@aaee2a2
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToOptionalConverter@664e5dee
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToOptionalConverter@664e5dee
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToOptionalConverter@664e5dee
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@f3021cb
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@f3021cb
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@f3021cb
    org.springframework.core.convert.support.StreamConverter@f3021cb
```

Comment: There's nothing at all to go on here.  [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: updated full stack trace. It does not tell me what went wrong so that the java process terminated

Comment: Strange.  I'm a Maven guy, so I'm kinda useless here :( - I would hope there'd be a little more info in some other log file or something.  Can't think of a case where Maven itself crashed, so nothing to even parallel here. - the tool itself crashing suggests a bug or configuration problem to me.  The project itself shouldn't be able to crash the tool if it's healthy and well configured.

Comment: Is your Gradle environment able to build other projects?  If you're not sure, maybe a "hello world" test would be appropriate.  Isolate the problem from your particular project if you can.  If it's just a particular project, then maybe you can morph between a simple project that works and the broken project, and see if you can isolate the exact cause.

Comment: This was working project until I upgraded to springboot 2 which requires Gradle 4.6+ so I had to upgrade both. I just ran one sample application which is springboot 2 + gradle. https://github.com/gothinkster/spring-boot-realworld-example-app. It's running properly but my application is not working.

Comment: is there anyway I can log everything related to spring framework? If it would be anything related to my code, it should give me some error related to application in stack trace.

Comment: As this is apparently coming from Gradle, which is a build tool, you're getting this error while building your app, not running it.  Therefore, I don't think the concept of logging for a particular part of your code would make sense.  If it has anything to do with Spring specifically, it would be with a Spring Gradle plugin, and I don't know if there would be any logging involved with that.  Since this is a build-time error, it seems to me that the problem would be very Gradle-centric, even if it involves some specific build step related to Spring.

Comment: In short - I'd tend to blame Gradle itself if you're getting a build-time error and no error information to go with it.

Comment: It's not failing while building. The build goes well. Then When I run ./gradlew bootRun, it reaches to a state where it says listening to port <my port> then it crashes before seeing Spring Boot message

Comment: If you see the detail stacktrace, the error is at bootRun.         at org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.exec(JavaExec.java:81)
        at org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun.exec(BootRun.java:51)

Comment: Ah, ok.  I didn't catch that this was about running your app via Gradle.  Sorry.  I've never found a reason to do that in Maven.  Can you run it outside of Gradle?  I'm wondering if you'll see more error information if you do so.  I'm curious what the advantage is to running it with Gradle.  Don't you need to ultimately run it without Gradle involved anyway?

Comment: After putting break points in SpringApplication.java, seeing error as "org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]"

Comment: Ah great.  Now we're getting somewhere.  Congrats on narrowing down on the problem.  So that error says to me that a String is being passed in where the Spring framework expects a SpringApplication object.  It's saying there's no converter for that because that isn't something with a natural conversion.  I expect that's due to an error in the code.  Look for which String it's talking about, and see if you can find where a String is being passed into a place that expects a SpringApplication object.

Comment: Just noticed you updated your question.  Looking...

Comment: I have updated my questions if you can find out but I am not seeing anything on my code. This is working fine for springboot version < 2. What is that special thing in springboot2 which causes this issue

Comment: I have multiple Spring Boot apps using pretty much the latest Spring Boot.  I can see this point in my IDE for one of my own projects. I'm not able to think of anything to tell you with what I'm seeing.  Maybe someone with more experience would know what this is.  For me, I'd need to see more of your code, like how you're setting up your Spring app.  Maybe you're doing something for older SB that isn't right any more.  Not sure.  A basic SB setup is just a few lines of code.